# How to iterate over an audio file in 20s intervals?

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, transcription

I am trying to transcribe an audio file which is about 3 min long using `SpeechRecognition`, however, it seems to be unable to transcribe anything longer than 20 seconds. This is the code that I'm using:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()

audio = FLAC(output_name +'.' + output_format)
audio_length = audio.info.length

file = sr.AudioFile(output_name +'.' + output_format)

with file as source:
    audio = r.record(source, duration = 20)

google = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU' )
print(google)
```

How can I loop this so that it transcribes 0s - 20s, then 20s - 40s and so on until the audio file ends?

I would want to avoid splitting the file into separate files of 20s length as much as possible.

Comment: Using hard seconds for the split is not enough I'm afraid. Just image being in the middle of a word.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen Yes, I know it's one of the problems, but it should be good enough for trying to make sense of the audio in foreign language (because you can input the transcription into Google Translate and hopefully get something that makes sense). 

As for tackling this problem, I was thinking of using SpeechRecognition time stamps for words for knowing when a word ends, and end the loop there, moving onto the next segment. However I wouldn't know how to do that without knowing the answer to the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. My bad for not reading the documentation of the SpeechRecognition module carefully enough, but they have an `offset` parameter!

```
count = 0
for audio_path in audio_files:
     audio = FLAC(audio_list[count] + '.' + output_format) #specify audio file for length calculation
     audio_length = audio.info.length #get length of audio file

     #n.b. mutagen module used for calculating audio length

     number_of_iterations = int(audio_length/20)

    if number_of_iterations == 0:
        number_of_iterations = 1

     file = sr.AudioFile(audio_list[count] + '.' + output_format)


    for i in range(number_of_iterations):
        with file as source:
            audio = r.record(source, offset = i*20, duration = 20)

         google = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU' )
         count = count + 1
         print(google)
```